# Python - shell command causes InterfaceError on file download

Tags: python

Recently, we replaced curl with aria2c in order to download files faster from our backend servers for later conversion to different formats.

Now for some reason we ran into the following issue with aria2c:

> Pool callback raised exception: InterfaceError(0, '')

It's not clear to us where this InterfaceError occurs or what it actually could mean. Besides, we can trigger the executed command manually without any problems.

Please also have a look at our download function:

```
def download_file(descriptor):
    """
    creates the WORKING_DIR structure and Download the descriptor. 
    The descriptor should be a URI (processed via aria2c)
    returns the created resource path
    """
    makedirs(WORKING_DIR + 'output/', exist_ok=True)

    file_path = WORKING_DIR + decompose_uri(descriptor)['fileNameExt']
    print(file_path)

    try:
        print(descriptor)
        exec_command(f'aria2c -x16 "{descriptor}" -o "{file_path}"')
    except CalledProcessError as err:
        log('DEBUG', f'Aria2C error: {err.stderr}')
        raise VodProcessingException("Download failed. Aria2C error")

    return file_path


def exec_command(string):
    """
    Shell command interface
    Returns returnCode, stdout, stderr
    """
    log('DEBUG', f'[Command] {string}')
    output = run(string, shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True)
    return output.returncode, output.stdout, output.stderr
```

Is stdout here maybe misunderstood by python which then drop into this InterfaceError?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I just wanted to use aria2c to download files faster, as it support multiple connection, I now switched over to a tool called "axel". It also supports multiple connections without the excessive overhead aria2c has, at least for me in this situation.